# Can I vectorize two for loops that look for the closest zip code based on lat/lon?

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization, reverse-geocoding

Question moved to CodeReview:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257465/can-i-optimize-two-for-loops-that-look-for-the-closest-zip-code-based-on-lat-lon
I am new to python and I had the task to find the US zip code based on latitude and longitude. After messing with arcgis I realized that this was giving me empty values for certain locations. I ended up coding something that accomplishes my task by taking a dataset containing all US codes and using Euclidean distance to determine the closest zip code based on their lat/lon. However, this takes approximately 1.3 seconds on average to compute which for my nearly million records will take a while as a need a zip code for each entry. I looked that vectorization is a thing on python to speed up tasks. But, I cannot find a way to apply it to my code. Here is my code and any feedback would be appreciated:

```
for j in range(len(myFile)):
    p1=0
    p1=0
    point1 = np.array((myFile["Latitude"][j], myFile["Longitude"][j]))  # This is the reference point
    i = 0
    resultZip = str(usZips["Zip"][0])
    dist = np.linalg.norm(point1 - np.array((float(usZips["Latitude"][0]), float(usZips["Longitude"][0]))))
    for i in range(0, len(usZips)):
        lat = float(usZips["Latitude"][i])
        lon = float(usZips["Longitude"][i])
        point2 = np.array((lat, lon))  # This will serve as the comparison from the dataset
        temp = np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2)
        if (temp <= dist):  # IF the temp euclidean distance is lower than the alread set it will:
            dist = temp  # set the new distance to temp and...
            resultZip = str(usZips["Zip"][i])  # will save the zip that has the same index as the new temp
            # p1=float(myFile["Latitude"][58435])
            # p2=float(myFile["Longitude"][58435])
        i += 1
```

I am aware Google also has a reverse geocoder API but it has a request limit per day.
The file called `myFile` is a csv file with the attributes userId, latitude, longitude, timestamp with about a million entries. The file usZips is public dataset with information about the city, lat, lon, zip and timezone with about 43k records of zips across the US.

Comment: Don't increment `i` in your `for` loop, `for i in range(0, len(usZips)):` does it for you

Comment: Please give small snippets of these files enough  to reproduce your code.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you performing this calculation for each of your million records? If so, try sorting the `usZips` by latitude and longitude first, then use search to prune the set of zip codes that you need to test for a specific record. There is no reason to even consider a zip code in California for a location in New York. Vectorization isn't the answer here, you need something better than a brute force algorithm, then vectorize it.

Comment: I will describe my files more in depth

Comment: The closer I read your question, the more it seems off-topic for SO, and a better candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Reducing the amount of records is a good idea; however, I am not sure my records are targeted to a single state. I am only given the lat and lon for my records as location information.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I will move it there, thank you so much

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835785/python-code-to-filter-closest-distance-pairs/63844625#63844625 ?

Comment: @user3184950 No, the question is asking for pairs while I need the closest zip given the lat/lon

Comment: How is the data containing the ZIP's stored? As a single point, or as a polygon? Because if it is stored as a single point, it is exactly the same

Comment: Please add sample data as pythondict/json, of both ZIP codes, and locations you want to mirror against. I will show a example

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `myFile` and `usZips` look like (I cannot verify the code). So, try something like this in the framework of vectorization:

```
your_needed_dist = 10 # for example
lat = float(usZips["Latitude"][0])
lon = float(usZips["Longitude"][0])

lat0 = np.array(myFile["Latitude"])
lon0 = np.array(myFile["Longitude"])
dist = np.sqrt((lat-lat0)**2 - (lon-lon0)**2)

condition = dist <= your_needed_dist

# get index (or indices) that satisfy dist <= your_needed_dist
np.argwhere(condition)

# or
resultsZip = str(usZips["Zip"][condition])
```

Also check the definition of distance in my code (this is what you need or not).

Comment: Oh let me describe my file

Comment: It looks a lot cleaner than my code already lol. I got a runtime error in `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  dist = np.sqrt((lat - lat0) ** 2 - (lon - lon0) ** 2)` and `ndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 1000000 instead of 43191` I meant to ask what is the purpose of `your_needed_dist`?

Comment: You can use `your_needed_dist = 0`. Or you can use it to find the zipcodes around some position.

Comment: About error, please check `lat`, `lon`, `lat0.shape` and `lon0.shape` to be sure that `lat` and `lon` are both scalars and `lat0` and `lon0` are arrays with the same size.

Comment: I still get the error in this case saying that lat has no such parameter

Comment: be sure that `lat` and `lon` are both scalars (float numbers) and `lat0` and `lon0` are numpy arrays with the same size.