# Need of Optimization of shortest distance calculation in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

| id | latlong_tuple |
| --- | --- |
| 364 | (17.3946820179646, 78.042644262359) |
| 365 | (17.3945761480423, 78.0427466415321) |
| 1085 | (17.3950200947952, 78.0432334533569) |
| 1086 | (17.3947638830589, 78.0430426797909) |
| 1087 | (17.3945460707558, 78.0430666916614) |

df2

| index | latlong_tuple |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | (17.431952, 78.37396) |
| 02 | (17.48295, 78.306694) |
| 03 | (17.479734, 78.34914) |
| 04 | (17.368366, 78.38604) |
| 05 | (17.433102, 78.37506) |

```
def tileId_mapping(sample_cord, tile_cord, tile):
    result = []
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(sample_cord))):
        dis_list=[]
        for j in range(0, len(tile_cord)):
            dis = hs.haversine(sample_cord[i], tile_cord[j], unit=Unit.METERS)
            dis_list.append(dis)
        shortest_dis = min(dis_list)
        min_index = dis_list.index(shortest_dis)
        result.append(id_tile[min_index])
    return result
```

This code is too slow to when the size of df1 is 320096 and df2 is 5299669. Can someone please help me to make it faster ?

Thanks in advance.

---

I want the df1.id against each df2.latlong_tuple. This df1.id should be assigned based on the shortest distance from df2.latlong_tuple.

I want result something like below ,

df2

| index        | latlong_tuple                     | Id |

|------          |-----------------------------------|----|

|             01 |(17.431952, 78.37396)              |356 |

Comment: You might want a geopandas spatial index. This can give you overlaps / intersections quickly. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query.html

For minimum distance in a graph see the networkx shortest path algo: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path

Comment: haversine_vector perhaps?

Comment: Also, using for loops like this is very inefficient. You should be able to vectorize the calculation with numpy / pandas.

Not sure if your haversine function is able to be vectorized, but I'm sure there is a vectorized implementation out there. In that case the O(N^2) approach will be faster than your current implementation.

Comment: Thanks Erotemic, I will try with numpy vectors and check.

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835785/python-code-to-filter-closest-distance-pairs/63844625#63844625 ?

Comment: Also, appending to a list is slow.  If you want to do it this way, try using a deque from the collections module.  It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `haversine` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453439/7456788)

First of all, you should have two columns, one for your latitude and the other one for your longitute.

You could use something like this:

```py
df1[['LAT', 'LONG']] = pd.DataFrame(df1['latlong_tuple'].to_list())

# same for the second dataframe
df2[['LAT', 'LONG']] = pd.DataFrame(df2['latlong_tuple'].to_list())
```

Then, compute the vectorized haversine function like so:

```py
# vectorized haversine function
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
    """
    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.
    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    
    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2
    
    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))


df1['dist'] = haversine(df1.LAT.shift(), df1.LONG.shift(), df2.LAT.shift(), df2.LONG.shift())
```

Comment: I want the df1.id against each df2.latlong_tuple. This df1.id should be assigned based on the shortest distance from df2.latlong_tuple.

I want result something like below ,
df2
| index | latlong_tuple | Id |
|------ |-----------------------------------|----|
| 01 |(17.431952, 78.37396) |356 |